# Finding duplicates of multi-page documents on distinct IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, having

Our hospital systems have a table for documents, and the pages are listed out individually, as well.  So, each document/subtitle/DUID (document unique ID) will be listed for EVERY page (page 1, page 2, page 3)  Here is an example of a table and what I'm trying to accomplish -

```
ID             Global_ID            document                subtitle                       page   DUID
-------------- -------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------------ ------ -------------
1              11111                IMAGING REPORT          20120723 6400 CR               1      1.2.840..... 
2              22222222             RADIOLOGY               20110808 70012240000200 CH2V   1      1.2.840.111. 
2              22222222             RADIOLOGY               20110808 70012240000200 CH2V   1      1.2.840.222. 
3              333333               IMAGING REPORT          20120607 29006850002500 CH2V3  1      1.2.840..... 
4              44444444             RADIOLOGY               20110816 70012240000300 CH1V   1      1.2.840..... 
5              55555555             RADIOLOGY               20110817 70012240000400 CH1V   1      1.2.840.....
```

I am trying to find "repeats", like ID#2 in the example... where the ID has TWO copies (each with their own unique DUID) of the same document/subtitle combination.  Keep in mind, I limited the above results to "page 1"... but that's fine, because that will shorten the overall result set.  ALso, please keep in mind that the subtitles for two different IDs can match, so I can't do a simple `COUNT(subtitle) > 1`
Please, help me find the duplicates, so we can clean up our records!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            N=COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Global_ID, document, subtitle)
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE N > 1
```

Comment: That would be great, but I'm still getting repeats of multiple page #'s

Comment: @user2460205 well, you said you wanted to find repeats, and that's what this query is doing

Comment: repeats where page = '1'

Comment: @user2460205 I don't understand what you want

Answer (score 1):

This will work -

```
;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT ID, Global_ID,DOCUMENT,subtitle, page, DUID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Global_ID,DOCUMENT,subtitle, page, DUID ORDER BY ID, Global_ID,DOCUMENT,subtitle, page, DUID DESC) AS row_cnt FROM table
)   
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE row_cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this...

```
SELECT A.ID,A.DUID,B.ID,B.DUID
FROM <TABLE> A Join <TABLE> B
ON A.ID=B.ID 
and A.Global_ID=B.Global_ID 
and A.document=B.document 
and A.subtitle=B.subtitle
and A.page=B.page
WHERE A.DUID<>B.DUID
```

Comment: THIS ^  I didn't even THINK of this... DOH!

Comment: great! I use some form of this at various times for a quick 'dup check'